# Can final volume differ from initial volume in a constant volume process?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, erratum

> A sample of 1.00 mol perfect gas molecules with $C_{p,\mathrm m} = 7R/2$ is put through the following cycle: (a) **constant-volume heating to twice its initial volume**, ...

(Problem 2.5, Atkins *Physical Chemistry* 8th ed.)

---

The problem says that in a constant volume process the final volume is twice the initial volume.

Is this even possible? How can volume become twice if it was constant all the time, it wouldn't have exploded to twice its size suddenly after the process ended right?

Comment: The question is obviously wrong. What's your source?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Physical Chemistry by Peter Atkins 8th ed. I took it from my school library.

Comment: Very odd. The question makes no sense as written. Constant volume is, well, constant, so you can't get twice the volume if the volume is held constant. Maybe have a look at an earlier or later edition of Atkins, see if this is an error introduced during a revision.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I don't have a previous version. Anyway the question is 2.5 in problems section.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt the 8th ed of Atkins indeed has this weird question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/enri8.png. The question has been removed in the 10th ed. It is very obviously wrong, I suspect it was meant to be constant pressure.

Comment: Next time, please include the source with it, and quote it verbatim. That allows people to better judge what's going on.

Comment: @orthocresol - Thanks for tracking that down. Guessing we can settle/close this question under the "typo" category?

Comment: @orthocresol I also thought it meant constant pressure but then in answers they gave work as zero which cannot happen in a constant pressure process.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes I do so next time I ask a question.